# preserving bit widths in enum in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

How do i preserve bit widths in Enum ?

For example in following code :-

```
typedef enum bit[2:0] {
b1=2'b10,
b2=3'b100
}b;


{// regular stuff module, initial begin etc..
b a1,a2;
a1=b1;
a2=b2;

$display("b=%0d %b",$bits(a1),a1); **// prints 3, 010**
$display("b=%0d %b",$bits(a2),a2); **// prints 3, 100**
}
```

How can I get to first statement printing 
prints 2, 10

I also tried following :-

```
typedef enum {

w1=2,
w2=3
}w;

w wa1,wa2;
int len,len2;
bit [3:0] bb;
{
bb=a1;
len=w1;
$display("b=%0d %b",$bits(bb[len:0]),wa1);
enter code here
bb=a2; len=w2;
$display("b=%0d %b",$bits(bb[len:0]),wa2);
}
```

**which has compile issue**.

Any other technique to preserve bit widths of variables/enums is also welcome.

--------------Edit after original question was posted-----------------

A simpler way to put this question is..

Lets say I have bit[31:0] a;

I need to achieve functionality as follows:-

```
  function bit[] get(bit[31:0] a, int size)
  return a[(size-1):0];
```

thanks,

Comment: I think `enum` can't be used in this purpose because it will give same bit width for every enum value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want in an `enum`.

When you write `typedef enum [2:0] {...} b;` you are defining a type called `b` whose width is 3.  All values of this type will (necessarily) have width 3.  A good way to think about this might be to consider a module that is going to take a `b` as an input, e.g.,

```
module mymod(input b myB, output o);
...
endmodule
```

How wide should `myB` be?  It needs to be wide enough for `mymod` to accept any argument of type `b`.  For instance, you would like to be able to pass this module either `b1` or `b2` and have it work.  But the module's input can't be changing its size dynamically as your simulation/hardware runs.

If you just want to have some named values that have independent widths, you might try using `localparam`, e.g., you can write:

```
localparam b1 = 2'b10;
localparam b2 = 3'b100;
```

But you'll still run into a similar issue when you try to assign these to your variables `a1` and `a2`.  At that point, it's just a matter of how wide `a1` and `a2` are.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you insist in using an `enum` you can achieve this implicitly:

`$display("b=%0d %0b", $clog2(a1+1), a1); **// prints 2,  10**
$display("b=%0d %0b", $clog2(a2+1), a2); **// prints 3, 100**`